# Lenovo z510 Touchpad

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, lenovo, mouse-scroll, scrolling

I have installed UBUNTU 14.04 on lenovo z510 but I can't scroll from the touchpad and I can't find the option of scrolling with two fingers in the touchpad settings from ubuntu settings

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try my solution? 
You just need upgrade linux kernel
http://www.hrupin.com/2014/11/how-to-fix-touchpad-scrolling-in-the-lenovo-z510-under-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Hope it helps

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Synaptics touchpad driver currently has unmet dependencies with Ubuntu 14.04 and cannot be installed. Try this solution, it worked for my Lenovo Thinkpad Edge 550.

[Synaptics Touchpad missing in Ubuntu 14.04.2 with Dell 5550](https://askubuntu.com/questions/623040/synaptics-touchpad-missing-in-ubuntu-14-04-2-with-dell-5550)

Comment: If your answer is essentially a referral to another question, it would be better to flag this question as a duplicate of the other (with the [flag] button below this one).