# Synaptics Touchpad missing in Ubuntu 14.04.2 with Dell 5550

Tags: 14.04, drivers, dell, synaptics

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04.2 on a new Dell Latitude E5550. 
I seem to have two problems.

One. When I run 'xinput' I get:

```
justin@sunkite:~$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer             id=2 [master pointer (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer   id=4 [slave pointer (2)]
⎜   ↳ ImPS/2 Generic Wheel Mouse   id=12 [slave pointer (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard            id=3 [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard  id=5 [slave keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                 id=6 [slave keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                    id=7 [slave keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                 id=8 [slave keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                 id=9 [slave keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD         id=10 [slave keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard id=11 [slave keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys             id=13 [slave keyboard (3)]
```

I expected to see a line with "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" but got none.

Two. When I try to install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics by:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

I get:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 xserver-xorg-input-synaptics : Depends: xorg-input-abi-20
                                Depends: xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.14.99.902)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

As a result I have no extended mouse settings.

[image]

Comment: First of all do not install  xserver-xorg-input-synaptics.In 14.04.2 it is another package. You can break your system. And give output of "dmesg | grep pnp".

Answer (score 1):

I would like to answer my own question as I solved this problem.

I discovered the Dell support web page [Latitude E5550/E5450/E5250 Ubuntu driver package (Ubuntu 14.04)](http://www.dell.com/support/home/il/en/ildhs1/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=03CD1)

I downloaded the [zip file](http://downloads.dell.com/FOLDER02334135M/1/E5x50_A00.fish.tar.gz).

After extracting I installed `touchpad-alps-trusty-dkms_20140325_all.deb` (a double-click brings up the Software application). I had to re-boot before I got the proper mouse settings become available. I am now able to use natural scrolling (as was my original goal).

Kindly compare the screenshot below to my original question.

[image]

Thank-you Dell for the page.

Comment: Do you have any idea of whether it will work for Ubuntu 14.10 on Latitude E5450?

Comment: +1 This solution also works well for Ubuntu 14.04.3 (64 bit) on an HP 8510W mobile workstation running on a T9300 Intel Duo Core CPU with the exact same initial symptoms and screens. Tx.

Comment: @Ankit: just try it and report here for others.